# Devices Endpoint - 400 required field error - deviceRegistrationId

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, nest-device-access

Getting the following error when calling the /devices endpoint:

https://smartdevicemanagement.googleapis.com/v1/enterprises/projectId/devices

- error code: 400
- message: deviceRegistrationId value must be set. This is a required field.
- status: INVALID_ARGUMENT

The API is being called from a Crestron home automation processor.  The same get devices api call (same projectId and tokens) works fine from Postman or CURL.  The documentation makes no reference to this error for the deviceRegistrationId parameter.

Comment: I'm unable to try the API. The evidence suggests that you're making (subtly) different calls. I encourage you to log the calls to see. The difference between [`list`](https://developers.google.com/nest/device-access/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.devices/list) and [`get`](https://developers.google.com/nest/device-access/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.devices/get) methods is the addition of the device ID. You say that you're using `get devices`. Are you trying to use `list` which doesn't require a device ID? Or are you using `get` which does? Could it be that a trailing `/` is causing the issue?

Comment: There is no deviceRegistrationId in the SDM API.  Is it coming from the "Crestron home automation processor"?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using that literal URL or did you replace "projectid" with your actual project id from the developer console?